# Suggestion for web application simmilar to wiki+SE

Tags: software, suggestions, custom-software

There were plenty of *.stackexchange places in which I could have posed this question. I hope I have chosen the right one.

I am looking for an open source wiki/stackexchange like application. The layout of stackexchange is almost fine to me, I'd just like it to be structured a little bit more like a wiki page.

There are plenty of options available so I am wondering what would you suggest to me so that it would best fit the following list of requirements:

1. The site would allow users to start new pages about some topic that interests them. There would be a template the OP would have to fill in (description, suggestions, external links) as on a Wiki page
2. On the bottom of every such page there would be a list of "answers" and comments that other users would contribute
3. There is an option to vote every answer. Moreover every post can be voted according to some attributes (importance, usefulness..)
4. Every answer and original post can be edited by anyone as on wikipedia
5. There is a flexible system for rating users (reputation system)

Can someone suggest me something that approximates the list of requirements?

Comment: Look for Open-Org on GitHub.

Comment: FYI there are lots of stackexchange clones: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Coordino](http://www.coordino.com/) and [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)???

I just tried both in one of my demo project and it worked fined. Please have a look at it.
I hope they will work for you. Open Source!!!